# Base Class For JSON Data

Tags: c#, json

I'm creating objects to store the JSON data I will be receiving and cannot figure out the right way to structure the objects. Basically, I can be receiving two different objects that only have differences in the body, so I wish to make a base class.

```
public class SampleBase
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string resource { get; set; }
    public string Body body { get; set; } 
}
```

This is an example of the base, with the Body object declared below

```
public abstract class Body{ }
```

I then have two separate files for the versions of the base object I can receive, with an example below:

```
 public class SampleObject : SampleBase
{
    public class Body
    {
        public string bodyproperty { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

I am doing this just to be efficient with the classes since they share some properties. The SampleBase class will never be called, instead incoming json will be deserialized into SampleObject. Is this best practice?

Edit: Going by this example, the JSON is received as

```
{
  "url": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "resource": "xxxxxxx",
  "body": {
    "bodyproperty": "xxxx", 
          }
}
```

Comment: It would help to see the JSON examples, plus why is Body property marked `abstract` only on the one example and not in the `SampleClass`

Comment: @maccettura Updated post with sample JSON. Marked body property as abstract in the base object because it will never be declared there, and instead only set depending on the derived object, since the two different derived object will have different properties in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class structure can heavily depend on your choice of serializer. For example, the `DataContractJsonSerializer` can technically handle inherited classes, but it does it in somewhat of a clunky way.  You need to define all the known inheritors of your base type *on* the base type.

Personally, I would use composition rather than inheritance in your case. Here's an example using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Wrapper<T> where T : Body
{
    [DataMember(Name = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "resource")]
    public string Resource { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "body")]
    public string T Body { get; set; } 
}

[DataContract]
public class Body
{
    [DataMember(Name = "bodyproperty")]
    public string BodyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd use the class like any other generic.

```
Wrapper<Body> obj = new Wrapper<Body>();
```

**Edit:** Since this is a MVC application, you'll likely be working with the `JavascriptSerializer`.  The `DataContract` and `DataMember` can be ignored but the structure of the classes is still relevant.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = serializer.Deserialize<Wrapper<Body>>(json);
```

Comment: The JSON is coming into a method in an MVC controller that is decorated with [HttpPost], so I simply add in a parameter to the method of the object I want it deserialized into